# Выборка 10 случайных записей из базы

Tags: php, mysqli

```
$Query = mysqli_query($CONNECT, "SELECT `name` FROM `table` WHERE `like` > 10 LIMIT 10");
```

Есть вот такой очень простой запрос на извлечение 10 записей из бд.

Помогите пожалуйста сделать так, чтоб 10 записей извлекались рандомно, то есть в случайном порядке.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL функция `RAND()` - то, что Вам нужно.

```
$Query = mysqli_query($CONNECT, "SELECT `name` FROM `table` WHERE `like` > 10 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10");
```

Comment: Да. спасибо! Приму ответ.